# Django url re_path failed to redirect to the correct view

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Django re_path did not match and I don't know the reason why.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ..
    re_path(r'^localDeliveryPayment\?paymentId\=(?P<UUID>[0-9-a-z]{32})$', verifyMobilePayReceived.as_view()),
    re_path(r'^localDeliveryPayment$', Payment.as_view(), name = 'localDeliveryPayment'),
    ..
]
```

If url
`www.example.com/localDeliveryPayment` the user is directed to Payment view.

If url `www.example.com/localDeliveryPayment?paymentId=00340000610febab0891e9008816d3e9` the user should be directed to verifyMobilePayReceived view. The problem is that right now `www.example.com/localDeliveryPayment?paymentId=00340000610febab0891e9008816d3e9` is still directed to Payment view.

Comment: The querystring (the part with `?paymentId=...`) is *not* part of the path.

Comment: You will thus have to make a more sophisticated view, that inspects `request.GET` whether it contains a `paymentId`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to capture a GET parameter in your URL routing which is the incorrect way of doing what you are trying to do.

Either continue with your current method of passing a paymentId GET parameter and check for its presence in you Payment.as_view() view OR you can rework this to something along the lines of.

```
    re_path(r'^localDeliveryPayment/<UUID:NAME_OF_UUID_IN_MODEL>/', verifyMobilePayReceived.as_view()),
```

This should provide the filtering for the model you desire.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing this out to me. I am still inexperienced and did not realize that the part ?paymetId is actually a parameter in request.GET